# camera and storage permissions isn't working in the webiew

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I'm loading my website in webview. And inside that website also contains two buttons "Take photo" and "Upload". In the browser on the phone it works perfectly. As in, the "Take photo" button lets you take a photo, and the "Upload" button lets you upload a photo. But inside my app, it doesn't seem to do anything. And I know this has something to do with permissions. Here's my code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favicon_1144_rounded"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test2">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I haven't changed my MainActivity.kt at all, but if you want, I can edit this question and add it in.

Comment: WebView does not handle permission. I used [Custom Tabs Implementation guide](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/implementation-guide) as a solution.

Comment: So It's not possible to do permissions in WebView?

Comment: No, you required the JS or something I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. From android app webview, you can not get access to device's permissions.